# Convert Datepicker to MM/DD/YYYY Format when submitting form

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, gravity-forms-plugin

I have created a subscription order form on my website with Gravity Forms. The form includes a date field formatted with a Datepicker. I added custom Javascript to limit the viable selection of dates to anything a day away. That code is as follows:

```
$('#input_14_11').datepicker({
minDate : '+1d'});
```

It serves its purpose and users are not able to select any past dates from the datepicker but a new issue has risen: The form cannot submit but instead returns an error message of "Please enter a valid date in the format (mm/dd/yyyy)." When I select a date it displays in the field the full date, example: (July 27,2022). However, when I manually enter a date in the specified format (07/27/2022), the form submits without an issue.

I essentially need to convert that selected "July 27,2022" into the correct format of 07/27/2022 when a user hits submit on the form. [Example of returned error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pplj3.png)

Comment: Which datepicker are you using? They usually have a parameter that you can use controls the format of the field.

Comment: @imvain2 Apologies if this isn't the info you are asking for in your question. I built it in Gravity's form builder and I selected the "Date" field type; from there in the "General" tab of the Date field, I selected "Date Picker" for the 'Date Input Type' (other options being 'Date Field' and 'Date Dropdown')and selected "mm/dd/yyyy" for the 'Date Format'

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#input_14_11" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',minDate : '+1d' });
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Thank you for this quick and simple fix! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating a new datepicker you could customize the one instantiated by Gravity Forms by using the [gform_datepicker_options_pre_init](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_datepicker_options_pre_init/) filter e.g.

```
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
    if ( formId == 14 && fieldId == 11 ) {
        optionsObj.minDate = '+1d';
    }
    return optionsObj;
});
```

By using this approach all the other datepicker properties, such as the date format, will remain the same.

Comment: Seriously thank you for the explanation; it helped me understand the process and I get to learn something new! It works beautifully and I am implementing on the site.